# height="x%" not functioning in <embed> tag

Tags: html, css, pdf, height, embed

I am using the embed tag to display a pdf file. It works perfectly, except for the fact that the "height" property won't work when I define height with % ("width" does what it's supposed to do). It works when I use px instead of %, and I have tried changing the numbers, but none work... Does anyone have any clue why?

Thank you!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<embed id="pdf" src="C:\path\Tysk.pdf" width="60%" height="80%"/>


<style>
#pdf {
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the  `<embed>`  tag, the height attribute must be displayed in pixels. Percentages are *not* allowed.

Try this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <style>
         #pdf {
           height: 800px;
           width: 600px;
         }
       </style>
     </head>
   <body>
     <embed id="pdf" src="C:\path\Tysk.pdf"/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

[Source on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)

Answer (score 0):

The `height=x%` is depend on the height of its parent element, because it's relative to its parent. In your case, `body` is the parent of `embed` element. So if you set a `height` property to your `body` element then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code works:

```
<style>
    embed {
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97vh;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <center>
        <embed src="your.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" />
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74354395/10802527
For a simple page all 3 behave identically their height and width must be defined in pixels or translated as %view, however browsers may add a frame embeding border of their own, so for height reduce a few points from 100vh similar reduce 100vw to avoid other embedment border/scrollbar anomalies each browser can vary but for Microsoft Edge I find style

```
 embed, iframe, object { 
 margin: 0!important;
 border: 0;
 width: calc(100vw - 18px)!important;
 min-height: calc(100vh - 18px)!important ;
 }
```

works more often than not or as shown below simpler `width: 99vw; height: 97vh;` is a good place to work from

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
html, body, embed, iframe, object { margin: 0!important; border: 0; width: 99vw; height: 97vh; }
</style>
</head><body><center>
<div>embed
<embed src="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#view=FitV" type="application/pdf" >
</div>
<div>object
<object data="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#view=FitV" type="application/pdf" typemustmatch="true" >an</object>
</div>
<div>iframe
<iframe src="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#view=FitV" style="border:none;" >an</iframe>
</div>
</center></body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this code will help your problem well, if you've not already tried this one.

```
    <object data="/pdf/mysample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="80%">

    </object>
```

Greetings.

Feel free to tell me the result of this try.

Comment: If it doesn't work, add this : min-height: yourpourcentage%; before the height="yourpourcentage%" of the embed tags.