# Set 100% browser height when embedding a PDF

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I try to make a very simple site that is only displaying an embedded PDF. The PDF viewer should have the same size as the browser window. However, I was unsuccessful in showing the full PDF height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html height="100vh" margin="0">
<body height="100vh" margin="0">
<embed src="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="100vh" 
 type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like this in different browser I tried (Safari, Chrome, Firefox - all on macOS Ventura): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPruB.png

I already tried to set the height to 100% instead or exchanging height with min-height. But for any reason, it does not work. Setting the margins/paddings to 0 as recommended in other posts has also no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on browser there is some need to avoid 100%, so PDF embed iFrame and object are usually handled exactly the same way, if the height is small the scrollbars appear even if not set by content see top left behaviour.

[image]

Setting Scrollbars to zer0 will usually be ignored and its much the same for toolbars and side pane, they will appear when needed by user interface.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><style>
html, body, embed, iframe, object { margin: 0!important; border: 0; width: 99vw; height: 97vh; }
</style></head><body><center>
  <embed src="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" />
</center></body></html>
```

[image]

The Anatomy of a browser is a Users Interface where they have full control
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this works. I set the height t99.99vh and the width to 100vw and it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

## Use CSS to Control Embedded Window Sizes

You were close, add the css properties like this and it should work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
embed {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <embed src="http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf">
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, however for any reason it only appears in the top left corner with this solution: https://ibb.co/ryJQsY4